# Unique instance TaskScheduler vs instance for each separate task

Tags: multithreading, spring, concurrency

I'm using the class
https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/scheduling/TaskScheduler.html
to manage the periodic execution of some tasks.
I have a set of separate tasks that must be executed periodically (operating on the same database)
What I'm doing actually is create a new TaskScheduler for each task

```
TaskScheduler scheduler = new ThreadPoolTaskScheduler();
    ((ThreadPoolTaskScheduler)scheduler).afterPropertiesSet();
scheduler.schedule(new task1(), new CronTrigger("* * */2 * * *"));
.....
TaskScheduler scheduler2 = new ThreadPoolTaskScheduler();
    ((ThreadPoolTaskScheduler)scheduler2).afterPropertiesSet();
scheduler2.schedule(new task2(), new CronTrigger("* * */10 * * *"));
```

I want just to understand if the better is to create a unique instance of TaskScheduler and use it to schedule all the tasks or there is no great advantage.
What is the interest of the pool in this case where the tasks are differents..

Answer (score 0):

In general it's the same. But you have to have some considerations.

If you have different kinds of tasks it's better group them in different schedulers. Probably you can stop some tasks of a type so having them in different schedulers let you do this without affect the others tasks.

If you have a lot of tasks it's better to have them in differents schedulers in this way the scheduler can manage them in a easier way.